Maximum of $\frac{x(1-x)}{x(1-a) +(1-x) a}$
The nominator of $\frac{x(1-x)}{x(1-a) +(1-x) a}$ where $a,x\in [0,1]$, is maximized at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. The derivative is zero for $x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a-a^2}}{2a-1}$ if $a>\frac{1}{2}$. How does one find the maximum in case $a<\frac{1}{2}$ i.e. how to argument that the maximum is then $x= \frac{1}{2}$.

Well, why do you say when $a<\frac12$, max is achieved by $x=\frac12$?  For e.g. when $a=\frac13$, it seems $x=\sqrt2-1$ gives the max.

For a given $a\in (0, 1)$ and all $x\in [0, 1]$, note $f(x) = \frac{x(1-x)}{x(1-a)+(1-x)a}> 0$. Hence maximising $f$ is the same as minimising
$$\frac1f = \frac{a}{x}+\frac{1-a}{1-x}\geqslant \frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{1-a})^2}{x+1-x}=1+2\sqrt{a(1-a)}$$
Here we have used CS inequality in Engel / Titu form.$$\implies f(x) \leqslant \frac1{1+2\sqrt{a(1-a)}}$$
with equality possible when $\sqrt{a}:\sqrt{1-a}=x:1-x$.  Hence this gives the maximum.

$$\frac{x(1-x)}{x(1-a) +(1-x) a}  =  \frac{1}{{1-a\over 1-x} + {a\over x}}$$
So we need to find a minimum of $$g(x)={1-a\over 1-x} + {a\over x}  $$ By Am-Gm inequality we have $$g(x) \geq 2\sqrt{(1-a)a\over (1-x)x} $$
with equality if $x=a$.

That approach is great, however you have not found the minimum for $g(x)$, only found another function which is a lower bound for it, and touches it when $x=a$.  For that to be a minimum, the RHS cannot depend on $x$.  For e.g. $x^2+1\geqslant 2x$ is correct and has equality when $x=1$, but the minimum is obviously when $x=0$.


Your initial assumption of fixing $x = 1/2$ is incorrect, as stated in the comment above.

We are looking for $\dfrac{d[x,a]}{dx} = 0$. But we have $2$ variables. So in order to eliminate $a$, we assume $x$ is the only independent variable since our max is w.r.t $x$. This means we assume $a$ is some function $x$, that can be written as $a(x)$.
By chain rule, we know $\dfrac{d[x,a]}{dx} = 0 = \dfrac{d[x,a]}{da} \cdot \dfrac{da}{dx} = \dfrac{-x(2x^2 - 3x + 1)}{(a + x - 2ax)^2} \cdot \dfrac{a - 2ax - x^2 + 2ax^2}{x(2x^2 - 3x + 1)}$
And so the $\max{\left[\dfrac{x(1-x)}{x(1-a) +(1-x) a}\right]}$ occurs when $-a + 2ax + x^2 - 2ax^2 = 0$ or
$$a = \dfrac{x^2}{2x^2 - 2x + 1}\,, \quad x \in [0, 1]$$
